# Restrict access to modules deployment console in alfresco 5.0.d

Tags: share, alfresco

In Alfresco 5.0.d even anonymouse user can access deployment console http://localhost:8080/share/service/modules/deploy    - how can I secure it?

Comment: I tried on Alfresco Community 5.0.d but it required me to provide username/password. Could you give some more detail about what you tried?

Answer (score 2):

The module deployment page (as with other Surf webscripts under service/ ) are restricted to admin by default.

See here for the webscript descriptor file which sets the admin authentication requirement: https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/surf/spring-surf/spring-surf/src/main/resources/webscripts/extensibility/moduleDeployment.get.desc.xml

```
<webscript>
  <shortname>Module Deployment Status</shortname><description>Displays the current module deployment status.</description>
  <url>/modules/deploy</url>
  <family>ModuleDeployment</family>
  <lifecycle>internal</lifecycle>
  <authentication>admin</authentication>
</webscript>
```